# Intent action to write in manifest for resolveActivity in API 30

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

The app needs to let the user pick a contact and take a picture. I'm checking if the user has an app that can handle those actions. I understand that you have to specify package visibility in the manifest file, but for the contacts, I don't know what exactly I have to write in the manifest. I thought that "android.intent.action.PICK" would be it but it isn't.

This is the code causing trouble

```
val packageManager: PackageManager = requireActivity().packageManager
val resolvedActivity: ResolveInfo? = packageManager.resolveActivity(
    pickContactIntent,
    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
)

if (resolvedActivity == null) {
    isEnabled = false
}
```

This is what I have in the manifest

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: What is the value of `pickContactIntent`? And, are you sure that you need to do `resolveActivity()`? If you just call `startActivityForResult()` and wrap that in `try`/`catch` (to handle the `ActivityNotFoundException`), you may be able to skip `resolveActivity()`. And, if you do that, you will not need `<queries>`.

Comment: val pickContactIntent = Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI
            )

Comment: I suppose I could do a try/catch block. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should also work if you change your manifest entry to:

```
 <queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```